# querying the google tag manager data layer using php

Tags: php, wordpress, google-tag-manager

**Has anyone ever queried the GTM JS datalayer directly from PHP?
So far I can't find anything by searching Google etc.**

Here's some context for readers:

1. I have a Wordpress website and am building a custom navigation
   system in my child theme function.php file.  As part of this
   ecosystem we have a .NET App that users log into. (Think of the WP
   site as a landing screen/intro/wrapper).
2. Google Tag Manager is used across both the Wordpress site and our
   .NET app.   The app populates the data layer with many things such
   as details about the user ie. username, userID, balance etc.  And,
   users can freely move between the App and the Wordpress site that
   sits in front of it.
3. Now, what I'm hoping to do in WordPress (from PHP) is actually query
   the GTM datalayer so I can grab the logged in user details etc. and
   present those inside my WordPress nav.

This approach may well be arse-about-face as I could probably also get such data from a Cookie within the domain BUT for interest sake I thought I'd go down this PHP route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GTM datalayer is a Javascript variable that exists only in the rendered frontend code. Since PHP runs on the server end of things it does not have access to the datalayer.

Well, technically you could do funny things like creating an AJAX call in the frontend to retrieve the page with the dataLayer and parse it, but that would be a very awkward way of doing things; it would be probably easier to hook into the serverside process that creates the dataLayer code in the first place.

If you want to get creative you could e.g. build a basic API of sorts that puts the datalayer values in a JSON object and load that from both your WP and .net pages - dataLayer as a service, so to speak. That still seems better than having your WP page scraping the .net app (which seems to be the only alternative).

Comment: Thank you kindly for your considered response.  I suppose it may be possible to render the bulk of my menu via PHP and then mix in some JS client side to dynamically write the required elements (from the GTM variable) in the front-end.

Comment: I've ended up finding a workaround.  The developers of our App expose a JSON file of user summary when a login is active.  As such I was able to parse that JSON into  PHP and then use that info to write the relevant user details into my WordPress pages.   This is lucky for me...

I'll leave the question open for a while in case anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: Actually, my apologies, of course I couldn't pull the player data from JSON into php as the user is not logged in on that machine (the server) and hence the player summary data I was accessing was empty with zeros in each field.

I ended up having to do everything front end.  Using PHP to supply the basic NAV structure but dynamically rewriting front-end elements after using some javascript to query my player JSON data.

So that worked just fine.